# attr_accessor needed for spec to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This might be the exact opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206196/attr-accessor-causes-rspec-tests-to-fail). Consider the following spec:

```rb
describe Record do
  it "calculates the first term grade" do
    test = stub(id: 1, final_grade: 20)
    audition = stub(id: 1, final_grade: 20)
    record = Record.create!({
      first_term_knowledge: 15,
      first_term_attitude: 10,
      first_term_test_id: test.id,
      first_term_audition_id: audition.id})

    record.calculated_grade.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

The `Record` model has all those attributes migrated into a db.

The spec fails with this explanation:

```
1) Record calculates the first term grade
    Failure/Error: record = Record.create!({
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
      unknown attribute: first_term_knowledge
    # ./spec/models/record_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The Rails docs state that `attr_accessor` must be set in order to mass assignment be allowed. I tried it and the test moves forward. However, this was a spike of development with no tests before hand and `first_term_knowledge` is successfully passed around.

How am I supposed to make the test work when production code already works with no `attr_accessor`? Is this a wrong way to test this? Should I use mocks for this or something?

Comment: Are you sure that the database includes that column? If you haven't yet run `rake db:test:prepare` you should.  `rake db:migrate` only migrates your development database, db:test:prepare does the same for your test DB.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks Brett, never realized I had to do such a thing. But then again, using `Record.create!` requires a db. Would mocks be a good practice to avoid db interaction?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you implemented the `calculated_grade` method but you might be able to get away with `Record.build` instead of `Record.create!`.  `build` gives you an unsaved object (but if `calculated_grade` doesn't hit the DB then you likely don't need the record to be saved).

Comment: Another awesome remark. I'll try and do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Brett Bender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92932/brett-bender) for answering this, great move!

`rake db:test:prepare` is necessary to have the whole schema loaded in the test environment.